# How to evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{(2x+1)\sqrt{3x+2}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int \frac{dx}{(2x+1)\sqrt{3x+2}}$$

I used the substitution,$$t=3x+2$$

Which leads to $$dt=3dx$$

But then the denominator becomes much more complex to simplify(I can show my working if necessary). Is my substitution wrong? 
Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do $x=\dfrac{y^2-2}3$ and $\mathrm dx=\dfrac23y\,\mathrm dy$, then your function becomes a rational function (because then $3x+2=y^2$).

Comment: Nice Substitution! Then it can be simplified to partial fractions to get an answer. Would you mind telling me how to find reference for these kind of substitutions? Because I find it hard to get the proper substitution for most problems. Thanks.

Comment: @emil I am not aware of a good reference for this. Perhaps that you might consider asking that as another question. In this case, I just thought that doing $3x+2=y^2$ would eliminate the square root.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Set $\sqrt{3x+2}=y\implies\dfrac{3dx}{2\sqrt{3x+2}}=dy$

$3x+2=y^2\iff2x+1=?$

Answer (score 1):

You should substitute $3x+2 = t^2$, then the given integral can be solved in the next step using the direct formula.